# Gradle sync failed: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.issues.SdkPlatformNotFoundException: Module: 'rn-secure-storage'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

`Android Studio Error: when I am trying to Generate Release APK, I got this error`

**Gradle sync failed: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.issues.SdkPlatformNotFoundException: Module: 'rn-secure-storage' platform 'android-28' not found.
[image: Here is my android studio error snapshot]**

Comment: RN version, more info

Comment: RN version:- 0.64.0  **Android Studio Error: when I am trying to Generate Release APK, I got this error**